# Implement a type trait for a class template that is true for the actual class template and classes that inherit it

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits, c++-concepts

I have a tuple-like class template like this

```cpp
template <class... T>
struct Foo {}
```

Now I need to implement something like this

```
template <class T>
void bar (const T& t)
{
    if constexpr (IsFoo<T>::value)
        // treat it as Foo
    else
        // a generic solution
}
```

`IsFoo` can be implemented straightforward like this

```
template <class T>
struct IsFoo : std::false_type {}

template <class... T>
struct IsFoo<Foo<T...>> : std::true_type {}
```

Now, I also need `IsFoo` to be true in case the type passed is publicly derived from any instantiation of `Foo`, e.g.

```
struct Derived : public Foo<int, float> {}
```

should also be treated like a `Foo` in the first `if constexpr` branch above.

However, I can't figure out how to properly implement a template specialisation of my `IsFoo` trait that would work when `Derived` is passed to it. But I'm sure Stackoverflow knows how to!

Edit: I found out that although all compilers used for the project support concepts, although there is no full C++ 20 support. So I decided to enable that in order to use the concepts-based solutions proposed.

Comment: I can only think of a type trait that can tell you if a class is derived (not necessarily publicly derived). See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of

Comment: One way is to put a marker inside Foo. Another is to have Foo publicly inherit a marker type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++20 concepts make things much easier:

```
template <class... Ts>
struct Foo {};

template<class T>
concept IsFoo = requires(T& t){ 
  []<class... Ts>(Foo<Ts...>&){}(t);  
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/qxh7zTohb)

Comment: Wow, this is impressive. I'm going to have an in-depth read on concepts now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Edited:
You can achieve it either with C++20 concepts (preferred, to be honest), but as you've mentioned C++17 in tags, you'll need to use the ugly way, i.e. `void_t`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ndWsc7ob1)
Basically all instances of Foo should share some common "tag", "marker" etc., you name it.
Protected derivation to prevent unwanted typecasts, `using` raises the tag up to public visibility and then the check for its public existence happnes inside `void_t`.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct FooBase
{
    struct FooTag{};
};

template<typename ...Args>
struct Foo : protected FooBase
{
    using FooBase::FooTag;
};

using FooIF = Foo<int, float>;
using FooIU = Foo<int, unsigned>;
using FooC = Foo<char>;

struct BarPub : public FooIF {};
struct BarPrv : private FooIU {};
struct BarPrt : protected FooC {};
struct Baz {};

template<typename T, typename=void>
struct is_publicly_derived_from_any_foo : std::false_type
{};

template<typename T>
struct is_publicly_derived_from_any_foo<T,
    std::void_t<decltype(typename T::FooTag{})>> 
    : std::true_type
{};

int main(int, char*[])
{
    std::cout << is_publicly_derived_from_any_foo<FooIF>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << is_publicly_derived_from_any_foo<FooC>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << is_publicly_derived_from_any_foo<FooIU>::value << "\n";

    std::cout << is_publicly_derived_from_any_foo<Baz>::value << "\n";

    std::cout << is_publicly_derived_from_any_foo<BarPub>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << is_publicly_derived_from_any_foo<BarPrv>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << is_publicly_derived_from_any_foo<BarPrt>::value << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Old answer below (not fully matching OP's use case) in case anyone needed it:**

You can take advantage of the fact, that if something is publicly derived from a class, it is also convertible to it, i.e. to its base type.

Now, depending what you exactly need in terms of detecting Foo the code might differ, but generally it should look +- like this:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G4TYY6s9a)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
           
template <class... T>
struct Foo {};

template <class T>
struct IsFoo : std::false_type {};

template <class... T>
struct IsFoo<Foo<T...>> : std::true_type {};


class BarPub : public Foo<int, float> {};
class BarPriv : private Foo<int, float> {};
class BarProt : protected Foo<int, float> {};
using FooIF = Foo<int, float>;


template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_public_base_of 
: std::conjunction<
        std::is_convertible<T, U>,
        std::is_base_of<U, T>>
{};
//extra disjunction with std::is_same<U,T>
//for fundamental types if it's also needed

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
struct typed_foo_or_publicly_derived:
    is_public_base_of<T, Foo<Args...>>
{}; 

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
struct any_foo_or_publicly_derived:
    std::disjunction<
        IsFoo<T>,
        is_public_base_of<T, Foo<Args...>>>
{}; 

int main()
{   
    std::cout << is_public_base_of<BarPub, Foo<int, float>>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << is_public_base_of<BarPriv, Foo<int, float>>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << is_public_base_of<BarProt, Foo<int, float>>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << is_public_base_of<FooIF, Foo<int, float>>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << typed_foo_or_publicly_derived<BarPub, int, float>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << typed_foo_or_publicly_derived<BarPriv, int, float>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << typed_foo_or_publicly_derived<BarProt, int, float>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << typed_foo_or_publicly_derived<FooIF, int, float>::value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does however not match my use-case excaxtly since it always specifies the template types expected. I want a solution that works without knowing the types, with a signature like e.g. `static_assert (any_foo_or_publicly_derived<BarPub>::value)`

Comment: @PluginPenguin see my answer now, please.

Comment: Thanks for your edited answer. I didn't think of using a tag here, but it makes sense. Unfortunately, the `Foo` class comes from a third party framework, so I cannot alter it (didn't mention that). I found out that all compilers used for that project have at least partial C++ 20 support and indeed all support concepts I'll go with that now, but otherwise this would have been the accepted answer :)

Comment: @PluginPenguin if you can use concepts, go for them, lucky you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
  #include <type_traits>
           
  template <class A, class B> class Foo {};
           
  class Bar : public Foo<int, float> {};
           
  template <class A, class B> 
  std::true_type checkFoo(const Foo<A,B>&);
      
  std::false_type checkFoo(...);
      
  int main()
  {   
      Bar bar;
      int baz;
      static_assert(decltype(checkFoo(bar))::value, "bar test failed");;
      static_assert(!decltype(checkFoo(baz))::value, "baz test failed");;
  }
```

Comment: This is a nice, simple approach, and shows it does not require tags to accomplish.  However, it can be further improved using variadic templates, and the decltype can be hidden away behind a variable template:  https://godbolt.org/z/79MqxqTGh

Answer (score 0):

My version with C++14 (can be tweaked to C++11 easily):

```cpp
template <template<typename...> typename T, class... U>
void callWithTemplateBase(const T<U...>&);

template <typename T, template<typename...> typename Base, typename U = void>
struct IsInstanceOfTemplate : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, template<typename...> typename Base>
struct IsInstanceOfTemplate<
        T, 
        Base, 
        decltype(callWithTemplateBase<Base>(std::declval<T>()))> 
    : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, template<typename...> typename Base>
constexpr bool IsInstanceOfTemplate_v = IsInstanceOfTemplate<T, Base>::value;


template <class... T>
struct Foo {};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool IsFoo_v = IsInstanceOfTemplate_v<T, Foo>;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sv7jTPbE6